# AM vs SSB weak signal

Tags: propagation

I know single sideband is much better than FM for weak signal receiving. I know that SSB is just like AM, but with the unneeded parts removed.

For weak signal propagation, like EME and aurora, would reception on AM or SSB be better?

Comment: As far as I know, more people do EME and Aurora with CW or JT65 or any similar close-to-the-background-noise level digital mode, than do it with voice.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't think anyone would be transmitting AM for weak signal work unless they were just fooling around.  You'd get the same effect by cutting your power by 3/4s.  In AM the carrier consumes 1/2 the power with the rest split between the side bands.  So, SSB is not only more efficient use of spectrum, it's more effective use of your power.

Comment: You also have at least twice the bandwidth (and consequently noise received) on the receiver end, because to actually receive *AM* you need twice the sideband bandwidth, rather than the sideband bandwidth as for SSB. So not only are you effectively cutting your useful *transmit* power by 6 dB through the carrier and double sideband nature of AM, you're also battling an additional 3 dB of noise on *receive* due to the wider receive bandwidth, for a total S/N reduction of 9 dB. That's a *lot* of S/N especially for weak-signal work.